# How to call an overriden superclass method from within a decorated subclass method

Tags: python, inheritance, decorator

I am trying to create a decorator which extends the function of a class method when the method is overriden by a subclass. Here's a minimal example:

```
class Parent(object):
    def __init__(self):
        return

    def say_hello(self):
        print('Parent says hello')

class Child1(Parent):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def say_hello(self):
        print('Child says hello')

child = Child1()
child.say_hello() # this will print 'Child says hello'
```

I'd like to create a decorator that will execute the parent's method in addition to the child's method.

```
def extendedmethod(method):
    def wrapper(obj):
        # call the method as defined by the superclass
        method(obj) # call the method defined by the subclass
    return wrapper

class Child2(Parent):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    @extendedmethod
    def say_hello(self):
        print('Child says hello')

child = Child2()
child.say_hello() # I want this to print 'Parent says hello' then 'Child says hello'
```

I think what I'm really asking is how do I access the superclass from which the subclass is derived from inside the decorator?

Comment: Can you please fix your code? The first won't print what you think it does, the second won't even compile to bytecode. Also, are you aware of ``super``?

Comment: The problem is that `super` needs to know which class and object is involved, information the compiler doesn't have access to inside `extendedmethod`.

Comment: I'm asking specifically to rule out whether this might be an XY problem that is solved by using ``super()`` *inside the method*, as opposed to adding a decorator.

Comment: I fixed the code, sorry about that. I have only ever used super to create a reference to the parent class so that I can call its contructor. I've never used it outside of this context and tbh I don't really understand it. How might it be used inside the overriden method in the child class?

Comment: If you add `super().say_hello()` before `print('Child says hello')` you will get the desired behaviour without a decorator. Is that not what you want?

Comment: Note that this is perfectly doable using a decorator. However, it requires writing a descriptor with knowledge of the ``function`` descriptor protocol. *If* an explicit ``super()`` solves your usecase, you should prefer that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In explicit code, we would be writing the following:

```py
class Child2(Parent):
    def say_hello(self):
        super().say_hello()  # call baseclass method
        print('Child says hello')
```

The argument-less form of `super()` is compiled to `super(__class__, self)` here, where `__class__ = Child2`. The important part is that `super` needs both the instance `self` and the *owning* class.

---

Getting the instance is simple – it is passed to the decorated method when called. The challenge is to extract the class on which the decorated method resides.

One approach is to design our decorator as a descriptor (similar to `property`) – descriptors can define a [method `__set_name__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__set_name__) to receive their name *and owning class*. In addition, we must define [`__get__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__get__) to satisfy the descriptor protocol and receive `self`, as well as [`__call__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__call__) to actually call the methods:

```py
class extendedmethod:
    """Decorator to call the superclass method before a method"""
    def __init__(self, method, owner=None):
        self.method = method
        self.owner = owner

    def __set_name__(self, owner, name):
        self.owner = owner

    def __get__(self, instance, owner=None):
        # self.__call__ with `__m_self__` and `__m_cls__` filled in
        return partial(self, instance, owner)

    def __call__(self, __m_self__, __m_cls__, *args, **kwargs):
        # self: the decorator instance
        # __m_self__: the `self` seen by a method
        # __m_cls__: the `cls` seen by a classmethod
        # super(__class__, self).say_hello ------------------------v 
        #      v super(__class__, self) ----v
        getattr(super(self.owner, __m_self__), self.method.__name__)(*args, **kwargs)
        return self.method.__get__(__m_self__, __m_cls__)(*args, **kwargs)
```

This decorator can be directly applied to a method to call its superclass method:

```py
class Child2(Parent):
    @extendedmethod
    def say_hello(self):
        print('Child says hello')

Child2().say_hello()
# Parent says hello
# Child says hello
```

Comment: Thank you. I definitely was overthinking this.